# Формирование XSLT файла

Tags: xml, xslt

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: преобразовать xml файл при помощи xslt. 
Задача [выложена на pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Qw3MdtcQ) из-за трудности вывода тегов.

В чем суть: пытаюсь по примеру в http://xpoint.ru/know-how/XML/XSLT/CookBook/Grouping выполнить свою задачу с помощью  **xsl:for-each-group**, но результат в конечном итоге - пустой файл, что бы я ни менял.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, решение:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="fruits">
  <fruits>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-by="./country">
      <country name="{./country}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <fruit>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="./name"/>
            </name>
          </fruit>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </country>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </fruits>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Проверял здесь: [Online XSL Transform](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html). Они поддерживают XSLT 2.0.

Во-вторых, в чем могла быть проблема.

Проблема может быть в том, что XSLT 2.0 до сих пор поддерживают не все производители XSL-процессоров. Например, msxsl (свободный трансформатор от MS) вернул:

```
>msxsl 1.xml outXML.xsl -o 2.xml         
Error occurred while executing stylesheet 'outXML.xsl'.   
Code:   0x80004005                                        
Keyword fruits may not contain xsl:for-each-group.
```

См. также [Wikipedia. XSLT Processor implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Processor_implementations)